# Playing Audio in Mobile -- Angular ng-click, DOM Exception 35 NotAllowedError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari, soundcloud

I have a website in production, pretty old site that I'm not interested in completely revamping.

I have a controller that grabs a bunch of tracks from a soundcloud playlist, and some code that loops over them

```
      <div class='song' ng-repeat="song in SCSongs track by $index" ng-click="$root.play(song, $index)">
        <i
          ng-show='$root.playing.id !== song.id'
          class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
        <i
          ng-show='$root.playing.id === song.id && !$root.playing.paused'
          class="fa fa-pause-circle-o"
          aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
        <i
          ng-show='$root.playing.id === song.id && $root.playing.paused'
          class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
        {{song.title}}
      </div>
```

Problem is since Safari 11 and a new version of Chrome is clicking the play button causes the  `Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

Do I need to be using html audio 5 controls, instead of a click-handler that leverages soundclouds `SC.play()` (Assuming this is basically `new Audio().play()`

The docs at safari aren't that helpful because it says that permission is granted if there is a click, which is exactly what I have.

I'd appreciate insight from someone who has dealt with something similar.  Do we need to use the `$event` to trigger a play?  This update must have broken all the things.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem, have you been able to make any progress on this ?

Comment: I️ ended up doing away with SC and hosting files from my own server. Workable for my use-case, but if you don’t have access to the files this obviously doesn’t work for you. No issues once the files were hosted from my own site. I️t probably has to do with the way the audio is streamed and the delay between the user click and the buffer. I tried preloading but no dice.

Comment: @Nuzzob did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Where use safari,you should give up the use of 'autoplay'.
To handle the DOM exception, you can attach a catch callback.

example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play().catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```